# datatables warning: table id=SH- Invalid JSON

Tags: array, condiciones

espero me puedan ayudar.
Actualmente Estoy trabajando en un crud y quiero resaltar el estatus de un color en mi lista de pedidos,  (color verde si el estatus esta activo y si esta inactivo colo rojo) sin embargo, cuando intento poner mi condicional en el arreglo me marca error, mi código es este:

Error:
localhost dice:
datatables warning: table id=SH- Invalid JSON

```
$subdata[]=$row[3]; 
$subdata[]=$row[4];  

if ($row[5] == 'Encontrado') {
        echo '<span class="label label-success">Encontrado</span>';
    } else if ($row[5] == 'Noencontrado') {
        echo '<span class="label label-danger">No encontrado</span>';
  
    }

$subdata[]=$row[6];
```

Como lo puedo acomodar?

Comment: estoy trabajando con los datatables y el error es el siguiente:

localhost dice:
datatables warning: table id=SH- Invalid JSON

Comment: ya lo agregue en la pregunta.

Comment: Saludos. Hace falta código, que permita identificar el JSON; que sea posible notar donde lo creas, donde se recibe y donde se usa (que es donde asumo se genera el error); te sugiero corroborar lo estas armando bien.